Получить массив пикселей кадра FFmpeg libav
Делаю игру на SFML. Делаю загрузчик видео на FFmpeg. Как мне из AVFrame получить массив пикселей кадра?
AVFrame::data просматривал, ничего не понял)

Скорее всего AVFrame содержит планарные каналы YCbCr и его необходимо будет преобразовать в AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 создав и настроив контекст swscale. Это может быть весьма медленным, так что имеет смысл (при наличии понимания) сделать вывод сразу в исходном формате, без преобразования в RGB на стороне CPU.
